# Квайны, зачем?

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день, господа знатоки.

Объясните, а лучше приведите пример, в котором необходимо (или просто пример) использование квайнов?

Да, имею я на выходе код программы (скрипта), а смысл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Квайны - это этюды. Музыканты разучивают этюды (музыкальные, конечно), что бы отточить какой то специфический прием/технику. Точно также и программисты оттачивают свое мастерство. Есть даже теория, что квайн можно написать на любом языке программирования - вот и делают. Можно пытаться сделать его поменьше или ограничить набором операторов.
Можно делать квайны-матрешки - к примеру, код на с++ выводит не свой код, а код на питоне, который в свою очередь выводит код на паскале, а тот - исходный код на с++. Как результат - хорошая разминка для мозга и отличная мерялка (для любителей).

Comment: Ок, впринципи ответ меня удовлетворил :D
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Смысл такой же, как в не имеющих никакого отношения к этому миру «учебных» задачках.

Решить (тренировка, самообучение), показать другим (развлечение, критика/обучение).

Comment: И только? 

Но разве нет ни какого применения, может кто-нибудь пример сможет привести?

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь, чтобы у программы, которая все что может — выводить код самой себя, была практическая прикладная ценность. Вирусы, в принципе, подойдут под возможное применение, но это не совсем квайны (нужно же еще зараженную программу запустить), да и квайны там не нужны.

Comment: Как говорила мой преподаватель по матанализу, "иногда интеграл это просто интеграл".